# is there a OSX 10.4 emulator i could run on an OS 10.8 mac?

Tags: mac, emulator

We have a program that will only run on mac OSX 10.4 but we need to get it to run on a computer running 10.8, is there any kind of 10.4 emulator we could use to get this to work?

Comment: I would just install 10.4 within a virtual machine.

Comment: would Virtualbox run 10.4 on a 10.8 mac?